# Get HTML Source in Android Studio

Tags: html, get, httpurlconnection

I test this function, but don't work
Permission is ok into manifest file
What's I doing wrong?

```
    public void getHTML() throws Exception {
    URL url = new URL("http://www.android.com/");
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        txtInfo.setText("123");
        br.close();
    }finally {
        urlConnection.disconnect();

    }
}
```

Comment: could you elaborate on what "don't work" means?  Error message?  Stack trace? Expected results versus observed results?

Comment: When I execute this code, the textview don't change the text. A error happens before this line: txtInfo.setText("123");

Answer (score 0):

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

You could also use AsynTask